# Check column value if has value = 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I went through some posts but I didn't find the answer that I was looking for. I don't use so much PHP and MYSQL in my work, but i have to create some demo for the page.

So i want to do this: With PHP i want to check in SQL database if column 'no' has value = 0, if it has then echo this, if has different value then echo this.

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE no = 0");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($row="0")
{
    echo "not confirmed";
}
    else
{
    echo "confirmed";
}
```

Comment: first you `print_r($row);` and add result in this question

Comment: 1) `$row` is __array__, 2) `=` means `assign`

Comment: Got it working guys by kRicha! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing you need to use this:

```
if ($row['no']=="0") {
    echo "not confirmed";
} else {
    echo "confirmed";
}
```

Comment: Great men, it is working! Cheers

Comment: @unforgiven np) just mark question as resolved)